# Slowing down Twilio text to voice playback in gather

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am attempting to use the SSMLProsody function to slow down the pace of playback for a persons name as well as a phone number.  I have used the space and period method for showing down the pace but I would like more control.  I see the SSMLProsody method has a "rate" that I would think would do the trick but I am not able to get it to work.  If anyone can help me with this I would appreciate it.  My code example:

```
var gather = new Gather(allowVoiceResponse ? new List<Gather.InputEnum>(new[] {Gather.InputEnum.Speech, Gather.InputEnum.Dtmf}) : new List<Gather.InputEnum>(new[] { Gather.InputEnum.Dtmf }),
                numDigits: 1,
                hints: "connect me, connect me now, connect",
                timeout: CallLoopTimeout,
                speechTimeout: "auto",
                action: new Uri($"{NotificationConfigurationManager.Configuration.TwilioVoiceApiAddress}ConnectVisitorCallback?{queryParams.GenerateQueryString()}"),
                method: "POST");

if (lowSpeechConfidence)
{
     gather.Play(new Uri($"{NotificationConfigurationManager.Configuration.TwilioVoiceApiAddress}GetSoundClip?siteId={siteId}&index=3"));
}
else
{
     var sayName = new Say(voice: Say.VoiceEnum.Man).SsmlProsody(queryParams.SpacedName, rate: "30%");
     var sayPhone = new Say(voice: Say.VoiceEnum.Man).SsmlProsody(queryParams.SpacedPhoneNumber, rate: "30%");
     gather.Play(new Uri($"{NotificationConfigurationManager.Configuration.TwilioVoiceApiAddress}GetSoundClip?siteId={siteId}&index=1"))
                    .Append(sayName)
                    .Play(new Uri($"{NotificationConfigurationManager.Configuration.TwilioVoiceApiAddress}GetSoundClip?siteId={siteId}&index=2"))
                    .Append(sayPhone);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The `<Prosody>` and other SSML commands are only supported when you use [Amazon's Polly voices](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/say/text-speech#amazon-polly).

So where you have:

```
var sayName = new Say(voice: Say.VoiceEnum.Man).SsmlProsody(queryParams.SpacedName, rate: "30%");
```

You'll need something like

```
var sayName = new Say(voice: Say.VoiceEnum.PollyJoanna).SsmlProsody(queryParams.SpacedName, rate: "30%");
```

You can also set the default voice within your Twilio console.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What if we are not using Polly?  Is there another way other than the periods and spaces to slow down the voice?

Comment: Therre is not. The SSML functionality is for Polly voices only.

Comment: philnash, can you tell me if I was to cut Polly on, on our account, will it continue to operate with the code as described above or will I have to have the SSML methods already in code when the cut over is made or will the older style api calls still work as they did?

Comment: Polly voices work with all existing TwiML. You can then enhance it with SSML when you're ready.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help with this and answering my questions.

Comment: No problem. Hope you get it all sorted.